# How do I place tkinter buttons in a specific area?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making a program for finding booking contacts with ease. When I type in all of this information, the buttons stay to the top left of the window.

[image]

How can I get them in the middle of the screen? Better, how would I place them where-ever I want in general? (Don't worry about the webbrowser import for that is for later in the program.)

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('GUI Booking')
root.geometry('600x400')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton", 
                font="TkDefaultFont", 
                height=20, 
                width=20,
                padding=10)
main_frame = Frame()
main_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

# Starting Window
button_location = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Location').grid(row=1, column=3)
button_name = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Name').grid(row=2, column=3)
button_email = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Email').grid(row=3, column=3)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a widget using grid()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33046790/how-to-horizontally-center-a-widget-using-grid)

Comment: This question is too broad. There are three geometry managers - pack, place, and grid, and each can be used to put widgets just about anywhere you want. They all have different strengths and weaknesses, and each are better than the others at some things, worse than others. The way to place a widget is highly dependent on other widgets, and what you expect to happen when there is extra space or not enough space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `.place` option instead of `.grid`:

```
...
Button = Button(something, text='Something', command=Something)
Button.place(x=value(e.g:2), y=value(e.g:2))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use row/column configure to center up the buttons: http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm
I've added this under your root configuration. Ultimately, the position of widgets will depend on the widgets that you use and adjusting their position with the grid manager.

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title('GUI Booking')
root.geometry('600x400')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Added to center buttons
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)  # Added to  center buttons

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton",
            font="TkDefaultFont",
            height=20,
            width=20,
            padding=10)
main_frame = Frame()


# Starting Window
button_location = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Location').grid(row=1, column=1)
button_name = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Name').grid(row=2, column=1)
button_email = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Email').grid(row=3, column=1)

main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want them to me in the middle of the screen, use `.pack` instead of `.grid`.

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
root.title('GUI Booking')
root.geometry('600x400')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton", 
                font="TkDefaultFont", 
                height=20, 
                width=20,
                padding=10)
main_frame=Frame()

# Starting Window
button_location = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Location').grid()
button_name = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Name').grid()
button_email = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Email').grid()
main_frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**warning: do not use `.pack` and `.grid` in the same window.**